# Can't run "phonegap run android", throws Exception

Tags: android, cordova

I wanted to start developing stuff with Phonegap and i followed the instructions on their website: http://phonegap.com/install/

When i am executing "phonegap run android" it gives me an error i could not find out how to fix. Here is my console output:

```
C:\Users\Christian>phonegap create my-app
[phonegap] missing library phonegap/www/3.3.0
[phonegap] downloading https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/arch
ive/3.3.0.tar.gz...
[phonegap] created project at C:\Users\Christian\my-app

C:\Users\Christian>cd my-app

C:\Users\Christian\my-app>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[phonegap] missing library cordova/android/3.3.0
[phonegap] downloading https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android
.git;a=snapshot;h=3.3.0;sf=tgz...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

C:\Users\Christian\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:12
6
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\Christian\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.
js:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Christian\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node
_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\Christian\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\
q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Christian\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\n
ode_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Christian\.cordova\lib\android\
cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\Christian\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\
q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Christian\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_mod
ules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

C:\Users\Christian\my-app>

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not have the android SDK. Check out http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android on how to get that installed.